# PowerShell: how to check how many digits were entered for user pin

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I'm trying to write a powershell script that asks for a user to input a 4 digit pin, and if the number is not equal to 4, a warning is issued.

Here's what I have but it doesn't seem to work...

```sh
[int]$userPin = read-host 'type in your user pin'
if ($userPin.length -ne 4) {
  write-host "Error, Pin must be 4 numbers"
}
```

this code writes the error message no matter what...
Any help is appreciated!
THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$userPin = while ($true) {
  $entered = Read-Host 'type in your user pin'
  if ($entered.Trim() -match '^\d{4}$') { [int] $entered; break }
  Write-Warning "$entered is not a 4-digit number; please try again."
}
```

The above keeps prompting until a 4-digit number is entered, and stores it as an `[int]` instance in variable `$userPin`.

Note that [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) matching is used *first* to ensure that exactly 4 decimal digits (`\d{4}`)<sup>[1]</sup> were entered, using `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match). That way, entering non-digits is ruled out up front, without causing the error you'd get if you cast a value with non-digits directly to `[int]`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

By *type-constraining* your `$userPin` variable to type `[int]` (`[int] $userPin = ...`), you force its value - both the initial value and any value assigned later - to that type, and an instance of `[int]` ([`System.Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int32)) has no `.Length` property (whereas the original `[string]` instance returned from [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) does).

By default, PowerShell ignores attempts to access non-existent properties and returns `$null`, so your `$userPin.length -ne 4` conditional is equivalent to `$null -ne 4`, which is *always* true.

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, `\d` matches not just the ASCII-range decimal digits `0` through `9`, but other Unicode characters classified as digits too. To disambiguate, you could use `[0-9]` instead, though that is probably very rarely needed in pratice.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

My take on [mklement0's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68514372/15339544), same concept, keep asking until user's input is 4 digits.

```
$inputBlock = {
    try
    {
        [validatescript({[regex]::Match($_,'^\d{4}$').Length -eq 4})]
        $UserInput = Read-Host 'Type in your user PIN'
        
        $UserInput
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "Error, PIN must be 4 numbers"
        & $inputBlock
    }
}

$userInput = & $inputBlock
```

Comment: No way, I didn't know you could call on a script block like that!

Comment: @AbrahamZinala you mean recursion on a scriptblock? hehe It's pretty cool right

Comment: If that's what it is haha yes. Really cool 

Comment: Thanks for your input!  I also knew there 'had to be a way' to make it loop until the answer was 4 digits! Awesome!